# Insert Data from POST Curl to JAVA Spring

Tags: java, php, spring, curl

i have this json POST url'http://localhost:8080/demo/test' from PHP

```
'{"postby_id":"1","title":"ftkjhg","is_private":"0","status":"1","post_type_id":"1","type":"2","p_id":"1","ve_id":"3","link":"1111111"}'
```

**my webController**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    @ResponseBody
    void creMysqlCall() throws Exception {


        creativityService.creMysqlCall();

    }
```

Service file

```
public void creMysqlCall() throws Exception {
        creativityDao.creMysqlCall();
    }
```

myDAO file

```
public void creMysqlCall() throws Exception {
        SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(masterJdbcTemplate).withTableName("posts")
                .usingColumns("postby_id","title","is_private","post_type_id","status","wall_type","p_id","ve_id","link");
        Map<String, Object> creInsertMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        creInsertMap.put("postby_id", "");
        creInsertMap.put("title", "");
        creInsertMap.put("is_private", "");
        creInsertMap.put("post_type_id", "");
        creInsertMap.put("status", "");
        creInsertMap.put("wall_type", "");
        creInsertMap.put("p_id", "");
        creInsertMap.put("ve_id", "");

        creInsertMap.put("link", "");
```

how can i post data from URL to this DAO am new to java thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

got this error

**HTTP ERROR 405
Problem accessing /backend/test. Reason:
    Request method 'GET' not supported**

New Class file using getter and setter

```
public class MysqlCall {


    public Object is_private;
    public Object postby_id;
    public Object title;

    public Object getPostby_id() {
        return postby_id;
    }

    public void setPostby_id(Object postby_id) {
        this.postby_id = postby_id;
    }

    public Object getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Object getIs_private() {
        return is_private;
    }

    public void setIs_private(String is_private) {
        this.is_private = is_private;
    }

    public Object getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Object getPost_type_id() {
        return post_type_id;
    }

    public void setPost_type_id(String post_type_id) {
        this.post_type_id = post_type_id;
    }

    public Object getWall_type() {
        return wall_type;
    }

    public void setWall_type(String wall_type) {
        this.wall_type = wall_type;
    }

    public Object getPostto_id() {
        return postto_id;
    }

    public void setPostto_id(String postto_id) {
        this.postto_id = postto_id;
    }

    public Object getVertical_id() {
        return vertical_id;
    }

    public void setVertical_id(String vertical_id) {
        this.vertical_id = vertical_id;
    }

    public Object getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Object status;
    public Object post_type_id;
    public Object wall_type;
    public Object postto_id;
    public Object vertical_id;
    public Object link;
```

**NEw DAO**

```
public void creMysqlCall(MysqlCall call) throws Exception {
        SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(masterJdbcTemplate).withTableName("posts")
                .usingColumns("postby_id","title","is_private","post_type_id","status","wall_type","postto_id","vertical_id","link");
        Map<String, Object> creInsertMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        creInsertMap.put("postby_id", call.postby_id);
        creInsertMap.put("title", call.title);
        creInsertMap.put("is_private", call.is_private);
        creInsertMap.put("post_type_id", call.post_type_id);
        creInsertMap.put("status", call.status);
        creInsertMap.put("wall_type", call.wall_type);
        creInsertMap.put("postto_id", call.postto_id);
        creInsertMap.put("vertical_id", call.vertical_id);
        creInsertMap.put("link", call.link);
```

**Service file**

```
public void creMysqlCall(MysqlCall call) throws Exception {
    creativityDao.creMysqlCall(call);
}
```

**Controller**

// API to test service call
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

void creMysqlCall(@RequestBody(required = true) MysqlCall call ) throws Exception {

```
creativityService.creMysqlCall(call);
```

}

Comment: Use tools like Postman or Advanced Rest Client (both have chrome extensions). You cannot do it from the URL of a browser unless the API received query parameters (which is for GET).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Spring MVC & Jackson question.
You have to create a class like:

```
public class MysqlCall {
   private String postby_id;
   /* the rest of the fields in JSON */
   /* getters and setters */
}
```

And then use the @RequestBody annotation to map it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Object creMysqlCall(@RequestBody(required = true) MysqlCall call) throws Exception {

    //creativityService.creMysqlCall(call);

    return call;
}
```

In the DAO you just link the object params with the sql mapping.

Comment: got this error
HTTP ERROR 405 Problem accessing /backend/test. Reason: Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: It would be great if you posted your entire controller and other code. This seems to be a problem with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Value Object class from your JSON with getter and setters.

Then your controller will look like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
void creMysqlCall(@RequestBody(required = true) MysqlCall call) throws Exception {
   creativityService.creMysqlCall(call);
}
```

Make sure you have Jackson in your classpath, so in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```